# Start index for iterating Python list

Tags: python, iteration

What is the best way to set a start index when iterating a list in Python. For example, I have a list of the days of the week - Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, ... Saturday - but I want to iterate through the list starting at Monday. What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Do you just want to loop until Saturday, or do you want it to wrap around and print Sunday last?

Comment: I just wanted to loop until Saturday. I hadn't realized until now that you can use slicing in Python lists.

Comment: is there a solution that deals with generators/iterables too and not only lists? Or really large lists?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation):

```
for item in some_list[2:]:
    # do stuff
```

This will start at the third element and iterate to the end.

Comment: Isn't this inefficient for large lists? I believe this slice operation has to copy the list elements that are being referenced into a new list.

Comment: Yes this is inefficient for large lists. See gnibblers answer below for a solution that doesn't copy.

Comment: how do u do this though if u are looping using a generators/iterables?

Comment: The you should use `islice`, as suggested in John La Rooy's answer.

Comment: @CharlieParker For more functions supporting generators/iterables, take a look at [toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.io), specifically [`drop`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.drop).

Comment: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @SanketParchande I've renamed the variable to avoid the name-clash with the builtin `list`. Don't name your list `list`.

Answer (score 59):

[`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) has the advantage that it doesn't need to copy part of the list

```
from itertools import islice
for day in islice(days, 1, None):
    ...
```

Answer (score 25):

Why are people using list slicing (slow because it copies to a new list), importing a library function, or trying to rotate an array for this?

Use a normal for-loop with `range(start, stop, step)` (where `start` and `step` are optional arguments).

For example, looping through an array starting at index 1:

```
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])
```

Comment: This should be the real answer

Answer (score 13):

You can always loop using an index counter the conventional C style looping:

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    print l[i+1]
```

It is always better to follow the "loop on every element" style because that's the normal thing to do, but if it gets in your way, just remember the conventional style is also supported, always.

Comment: This doesn't work for when you want to start at i=arbitrary index selected in another part of code. Also it doesn't work to first take a slice of the range because then the numbers of the indexes don't line up. Yes that can be accounted for but it's super annoying!

Answer (score 11):

stdlib will hook you up son!

[`deque.rotate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque.rotate):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

from collections import deque

a = deque('Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday'.split(' '))
a.rotate(3)
deque(['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'])
```

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is to print from `Monday` onwards, you can use `list`'s `index` method to find the position where "Monday" is in the list, and iterate from there as explained in other posts. Using `list.index` saves you hard-coding the index for "Monday", which is a potential source of error:

```
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
for d in days[days.index('Monday'):] :
   print d
```

Comment: really nice solution!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a rotation generator which doesn't need to make a warped copy of the input sequence ... may be useful if the input sequence is much larger than 7 items.

```
>>> def rotated_sequence(seq, start_index):
...     n = len(seq)
...     for i in xrange(n):
...         yield seq[(i + start_index) % n]
...
>>> s = 'su m tu w th f sa'.split()
>>> list(rotated_sequence(s, s.index('m')))
['m', 'tu', 'w', 'th', 'f', 'sa', 'su']
>>>
```

Comment: Yes - and would be easy to extend to generate an infinite recurring sequence.

Comment: can't help thanking @JohnMachin: great work for someone dead these 264 years

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "wrap around" and effectively rotate the list to start with Monday (rather than just chop off the items prior to Monday):

```
dayNames = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
            'Friday', 'Saturday',  ]

startDayName = 'Monday'

startIndex = dayNames.index( startDayName )
print ( startIndex )

rotatedDayNames = dayNames[ startIndex: ] + dayNames [ :startIndex ]

for x in rotatedDayNames:
    print ( x )
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop whole list (not just part) starting from a random pos efficiently:

```
import random
arr = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
cln = len(arr)
start = random.randint(0, cln-1)
i = 0
while i < cln:
    pos = i+start
    print(arr[pos if pos<cln else pos-cln])
    i += 1
```