# How to iterate a list starting from different index, and also wrap around

Tags: python, list

Similar question asked here ([Start index for iterating Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148619/start-index-for-iterating-python-list)), but I need one more thing.

Assume I have a list [Sunday, Monday, ...Saturday],
and I want to iterate the list starting from different position, wrap around and complete the loop.
For example

```py
a = [Sunday, Monday, ...Saturday]
for i in range(7):
    print("----")
    for j in (SOMETHING):
        print(j)

OUTPUT:
----
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
----
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
----
Tuesday
.
.
.
Friday
```

How could I approach this?

Comment: I got a eureka moment.
```python
a[i:]+a[:i]
```
will do.
I am not going to retract this post because I consider it might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: then you should put this comment as an answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to rotate a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381/circular-list-iterator-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import repeat

d = deque(['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'])

n = 7
for i in repeat(d, n):
    print(*i, sep='\n')
    print('-----')
    i.rotate(-1)
```

---

```
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
-----
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
-----
Tuesday
.
.
.
```

---

Though you might find more interesting to create a nested list:

```
n = 7
l = []
for i in repeat(d, n):
    sl = []
    for j in i:
        sl.append(j)
    l.append(sl)
    i.rotate(-1)
```

---

```
print(l)
# [['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'], 
#  ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this approach create 7 lists in the memory?

Comment: `repeat` is wimsply repeating the fed iterator 7 times, and here the result is simply printed, which seems to be what you trying to do @user12062120

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by:

```py
a[i:]+a[:i]
```

Comment: It will cause a new list creation

Answer (score 1):

You could pop the start item off and add it to the end.

```
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
for _ in range(7):
    print("----")
    print("\n".join(days))
    days.append(days.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.dequeue`, which has a `rotate` method. However, if you want to make it on your own you can do it like this:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> counter = 0
>>> start_index=2
>>> while counter < len(a):
...     print(a[start_index])
...     start_index+=1
...     counter += 1
...     if start_index==len(a):
...             start_index=0
... 
c
d
a
b
```

This is quite optimal, because you do not need to make any copy or create a new list, just iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```py
from itertools import cycle

counter = 1
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
for day in cycle(days):
    print(day)
    counter += 1
    if counter == 7:
        print('-----')
        counter = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```
def cycle_list(l, i):
 for element in l[i:]:
  yield element
 for element in l[:i]:
  yield element
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import any libraries.

```
DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
for i in range(7):
    print("----")
    for j in range(len(DAYS)):
        print(DAYS[(j+i) % len(DAYS)])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the elements starting from your current index (in your case the current index is `i`) with the elements before current index using generators, in this way you will not create new lists, will be memory-efficient:

```
a = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

from itertools import chain
for i in range(7):
    print("----")
    for j in chain((e for e in a[i:]), (e for e in a[:i])):
        print(j)
```

output:

```
----
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
----
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
----
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
----
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
----
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
----
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
----
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```